# Entity Framework - Include ALL related entities recursively

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have the following entities/relations:

- `Parent` to `OptionalChild` 0:1
- `OptionalChild` to `OptionalGrandchild` 0:1

If I want to delete a `Parent` I also want to delete its children and its childrens' children and so forth.

The way I currently accomplish this requires knowing ahead of time the whole chain of dependents:

```
myContext.OptionalChildren.Remove(myContext.OptionalChildren.Include(o => o.OptionalGrandchild).Single(o => o.Name.Equals("childName")));
myContext.Parents.Remove(myContext.Parents.Include(p => p.OptionalChild).Single(p => p.Name.Equals("parentName")));
```

Is there some way I can tell EF to search through the tree and do this for me so that I could do something like:

```
myContext.Parents.Remove(myContext.Parents.IncludeRecursively().Single(p => p.Name.Equals("parentName")));
```

Edit:

I've already set up cascade deletes but for some reason they don't take (see heavily-related question [Multiplicity constraint violations with optional-required EF Code First + Fluent relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368773/multiplicity-constraint-violations-with-optional-required-ef-code-first-fluent)) unless I include them explicitly. My class hierarchy is the same as the one in the linked question except this one has grandchildren.

Also, if it is relevant, I am using the "table-per-type" strategy where all three objects I mention here descend from a common ancestor that contains the PK, ie:

- `CommonAncestor` has `Guid ID`
- `Parent`, `OptionalChild`, and `OptionalGrandchild` all descend from `CommonAncestor`

The fluent configuration looks like:

```
builder.Entity<Parent>().HasOptional<OptionalChild>(p => p.OptionalChild).WithRequired(c => c.Parent).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

builder.Entity<OptionalChild>().HasOptional<OptionalGrandchild>(c => c.OptionalGrandchild).WithRequired(g => g.OptionalChild).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: could you not set up cascade deletes in your DB?

Comment: I did not set them up in the DB directly but I did through EF, but it does not work. I understand though that EF doesn't set up cascading deletes in the DB... Maybe I should add that info to the question.